# LINQ filter returned objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have this snippet in a WPF project, and I want to modify the returned objects to include only CardGroup items that have company_id = ?. Not sure how to do it, never done WPF before and never seen a snippet where the results are immediately returned as ojects like here?

WOuld be great if someone could just give me a heads up on the solution (which is probably pretty simple I would assume, but can't figure out where to place the limitation code).

```
    public List<CompanyComboData> AvailableCardGroupsForCompany(int companyId)
    => _dataService.GetAll<CardGroup>().Select(x => new CompanyComboData
    {
    Id = x.Id,
    Value = x.Name
    }).ToList();
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter using "Where". For example:

```
_dataService.GetAll<CardGroup>().Where(c => c.company_id == ?).Select(...
```

EDIT to change = to ==

Comment: Just had to change to c.company_id ==, and it works fine.

Comment: oops :) sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

```
_dataService.GetAll<CardGroup>().Where(x=> x.company_id == myCompanyId)
```

Comment: Thanks, preferred the above solution by @gcaton where he also showed that .Select(... would come after.

Comment: Yeah his solution had extra to mine, I was only answering your question, not rewriting your code ;) But problem solved